# Iterating with map, why is this not working?

Tags: javascript, loops

The javascript code is here:

```
function hidepre() {
    var pre = this.getElementsByTagName("pre")[0]
    if (pre.style.display === "none") {
        pre.style.display = "block";
    } else {
        pre.style.display = "none";
    }
}
function hidepreall() {
    var prewraps = document.getElementsByClassName("prewrap");
    if(prewraps.length > 0) {
        for (var i = 0; i < prewraps.length; i++) {
            var prewrap = prewraps[i];
            prewrap.onclick = hidepre;
        }
    }
}
window.onload = hidepreall;
```

This works fine in my firefox, but if I use the for(var i in obj) form, like this

```
    for (var prewrap in prewraps) {
        prewrap.onclick = hidepre;
    }
```

it stops working.

http://jsfiddle.net/5DmuE/1/
http://jsfiddle.net/5DmuE/2/

Both fiddles are not working in both cases.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `for-in` loop is not for looping through entries in arrays or array-like things (what you get back from `getElementsByClassName` is an array-like object called a `NodeList`). It's for looping through the enumerable names of properties of an object. Using `for-in` on a host-provided object (like a `NodeList`) is not guaranteed to work.

Use a nice simple `for` loop, or convert the `NodeList` into an array and use `forEach` on it (you can shim `forEach` on the few remaining browsers that don't have it). Here's an example:

```
Array.prototype.slice.call(prewraps, 0).forEach(function(element) {
    // ...use the element here
});
```

(The `slice` thing is a convenient way to create an array out of any array-like object.)

More about looping through arrays [in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9329446/for-each-in-an-array-how-to-do-that-in-javascript/9329476#9329476).

More about `for-in` on my blog: [*Myths and realities of `for-in`*](http://blog.niftysnippets.org/2010/11/myths-and-realities-of-forin.html)